# I can't get my HDMI port to work on my AMD Redwood GPU

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 19.04, motherboard

I can't get my HDMI port to work on my AMD Redwood GPU. I know it is a 5000 series, but I don't know which model exactly. It was given to me by a friend.

I know that the cable works because another HDMI port on the motherboard is working with this cable. I'm trying to run two monitors, but this is giving me issues.

I am running Ubuntu 19.04

Any ideas?

---

CORRECTION: The HDMI port that won't work is actually on the motherboard. VGA isn't working either.

Also, I think the issue is my Ryzen 5 2600 cpu and Asus B350-Plus motherboard. I flashed the BIOS to the most recent version (5007), but it's still not working.

Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: Are you connecting both the the AMD card?

Comment: I actually had that wrong... The HDMI port that won't work is actually on the motherboard. VGA isn't working either. The graphics card HDMI port is working.

Comment: So there is no issue after all, just misunderstanding. Ryzen 5 2600 has no iGPU and neither has the motherboard and that's why its video ports don't work and no, obviously there's no workaround. Better check specifications next time.